# Getting Error in converting string to date from textbox in webform

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I am getting error in converting string to date. I don't want to use calendar control because date has to generate at runtime and textbox and not editable.

### error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

### ASP

```cs
txtBoxRemediationDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d/m/yyyy");
```

### C# class

```cs
_assessmentRemidationObject.RemediationRecommendedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBoxRemediationDate.Text);
```

### Model

```cs
public DateTime RemediationRecommendedDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above is currently setting the Month element to minutes, so:

```
txtBoxRemediationDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d/m/yyyy");
```

Sets the value to "14/23/2015" (an invalid date) at 17:23 on 14/09/15.

Try changing "m" to "M":

```
txtBoxRemediationDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

This sets the value to the correctly formatted date today: "14/9/2015".

Have a look here for more formatting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx